# Send email to user of google hangout

Tags: email, youtube, hangouts-api

I'm wondering if there is some way to send an email to participant in a google hangout.  We'd like to adjust our hangout on air app so that when broadcasting in finished, all the participants would be send a link to the recording on youtube.

We've been looking through the Hangout API:

https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.html#gapi.hangout.Participant

Superfically I guess we can't - we get the participants google ids, but I guess that's as far as we can go?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You would likely have to ask them for it in some other means.

Answer (score -1):

There are 3rd party apps that can be used with Hangout On Air to get registration info... checkout Business-Hangouts.com to see how they do it.

AFAIK, there is no way to get the info directly from Google using their API.